# Algo sucedió el 1 y 11 de abril, 18 de mayo. ¿Alguien sabe qué?

Tags: discusión

El primero y el once de abril del 2016 tuvimos un salto significante an actividad en el sitio.  Lo mismo sucedió el 18 de mayo.  Tuvimos más participación en esos tres días y me gustaría saber la razón.  ¿Alguien sabe lo que ocurrió?

Tengo pensado que fue un enlace compartido en un foro o por las redes sociales.

Si saben de algo, por favor compartan.

Comment: ¿Estará relacionado con el inicio de clases de universidades/institutos en sudamérica?  En mi país el semestre inicia a finales de marzo o inicios de abril.  Podría tener correlación con las preguntas de *"homework"*.

Comment: Si, puede ser...

Comment: concuerdo con @Equiso, considerando que inician clases la tercera semana de marzo, mientras se pasan la voz, se registran y visitan, siento que encaja, sobre todo que por esas fechas creo haber visto mas preguntas del tipo: "Haz mi tarea", deberíamos habilitar aulas 2.0

Answer (score 4):

Pues yo recién descubrí que StackOverFlow estaba disponible en español y fue entonces cuando me inscribí y comencé con actividad.

Comment: Nos alegra tenerte por aquí. ¡Bienvenido al sitio!

Comment: Muchas gracias estoy para ayudar...

Comment: excelente, llama a toda la gente con la que estudias, estudiando entre todos, todos nos beneficiamos :D

Answer (score 2):

Mirando un poco el analis del sitio...

Esos tres días hubo mas preguntas y respuestas que de costumbre y el 18 de mayo en especial hubo muchos mas votos que los usual.

Sin embargo la cantidad de visitas al sitio se mantuvo dentro de la curva que ya traía.

No parece que tenga relación con alguna publicación en un foro o similar ya que la variable "nuevos visitantes" no tiene un movimiento especial en ninguna de esas fechas.

Evidencias:

Publicaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Visitas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, lo que se afecto aquí es más actividad - ya sean publicaciones, preguntas o respuestas.  Esos tres picos indican que algo sucedió esos días.  No fue el tráfico - fue la actividad. Me gustaría saber lo que fue. :D

Comment: Los títulos de las flechas que correspondientes al 18 de mayo dicen marzo :)

Comment: Perece que fue un typo pero corresponden a mayo. Gracias por avisar

Answer (score 1):

Fui yo el culpable de esos saltos significantes. Es que me desespere por resolver mi problema y empece  a preguntar por todos lados! jajaja

Comment: ¿Dónde más preguntaste? Cuéntanos :D